# Deploying to Google App Engine from Cloudbees

Tags: google-app-engine, cloudbees

I'm trying the CloudBees / Jenkins / Maven / Git deployment process.

I've successfully managed to set up Git, Maven and Cloudbees CI but can not deploy to Google App Engine.

In this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=L4d2HvXNfv0#at=35

The presenter selects a post-build step of deploying to GAE, but when I get there, I only get the option of "Deploy Applications" - with no option for GAE.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login into https://appengine.cloudbees.com/index.html once to appengine-enable your cloudbees jenkins instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply - but I've done that and there's still no deploy to GAE option in the post-build step drop down menu.... Any ideas? I've made sure I log in to  https://appengine.cloudbees.com/index.html with my gmail account that my GAE app is registered under... I'm stuck!

Comment: OK - I've almost worked it out. It's different to the video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=L4d2HvXNfv0#at=35)... In the build post-step, There's no "Deploy to GAE" (as there is in the video...) instead, select the first option: "Deploy Applications", then in the bottom of the box that appears, click the "Add Host Service", and select "GAE (Java)". THink thats it. ...     But now, have another issue... I don't know what to put in the "Fixed directory/ Application directory" text box.. in the vid, he puts in target/simple-webapp/ - but doesnt explain why.

Comment: And my build fails, due to exception: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate /scratch/jenkins/workspace/myapp-build/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml